# ManagedScheduledExecutorService in TomEE

Tags: java, tomcat, concurrency, ejb, apache-tomee

My application uses a `ManagedScheduledExecutorService` provided by the container (TomEE), injected via a `@Resource` annotation.

Is this my own instance, or is it shared with other webapps running in the same container?

As part of a graceful shutdown of my app, do I want to do anything to this service?

Answer (score -1):

The spec is only dealing with responsibilities and behavior (e.g. see JSR-236: EE Concurrency Utilities 1.0 - Chapter 3.2)

TomEE is provding a documentation regarding implementation specific configuration of managed resources: [TomEE - configuration of managed resources](https://tomee.apache.org/admin/configuration/resources.html)

> Is this my own instance, or is it shared with other webapps running in the same container?

Documentation provides this info: "In TomEE resources are mainly 'singleton'..."

> As part of a graceful shutdown of my app, do I want to do anything to this service?

The service lifecyle is container managed (see the spec).

Comment: The documentation is typically tomEE-vague: "In TomEE resources are mainly "singleton" (understood as defined once per server or application)." 

"Mainly" means that we can't tell whether or not this sentence is meant to include the managed scheduled executor service. 

And then the sentence goes on to explicitly state, "We're not telling you whether it's once per server or once per application; it might be either."

Comment: The information you are looking for is not covered by spec and documented vague. You should not rely on details not specified nor documented, since they might change without notice. Perhaps it might help if you could outline why you are asking and how you try to interpret the answer.